# The discount parameter does not come in the products array in firebase analytics

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

how do I send parameters to analytics

```
override fun addToBasket(product: Products) {

        val orderDiscount = MathUtils.discount(product.price, product.oldPrice)

        val bundle = Bundle().apply {
            putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, product.id.toString())
            putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_NAME, product.name)
            putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.DISCOUNT, orderDiscount.toDouble())
            putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_CATEGORY, product.categoryName.orEmpty())
            putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE, product.price.toDouble())
            putLong(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.QUANTITY, product.count.toLong())
        }

        val params = Bundle().apply {
            putParcelableArrayList(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEMS, arrayListOf(bundle))
            putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CURRENCY, "RUB")
            putInt(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE, product.price)
        }
        analytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.ADD_TO_CART, params)
    }
```

How are displayed in the items array in firebase analytics
**[here (image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t5O0F.png)**

As you can see the discount parameter does not come

Answer (score 0):

I am also encountering this issue. Discount value is properly added in the logs but upon checking the firebase debugview, it does not show up. Any solution/workaround?